# System.Threading.CancellationToken Not marked as serializable When using quartz.net 3.0

Tags: c#-4.0, serialization, quartz.net

When using quartz.net 3.0 new version,I met the problem:

> System.Threading.CancellationToken Not marked as serializable

here is my code:

```
    var properties = new NameValueCollection();
    properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy"] = "true";
    properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy.address"] = "tcp://localhost:777/Scheduler";
    properties["quartz.serializer.type"] = "json";
    ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new 
    StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
    var scheduler =await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
    await scheduler.GetJobGroupNames();
```

As the code run,I can get the object *scheduler* ,but when execute *GetJobGroupNames()* function,I got the error *System.Threading.CancellationToken Not marked as serializable*,so I view the source code in github:

```
public virtual Task<IReadOnlyCollection<string>> GetJobGroupNames(
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    return CallInGuard(x => x.GetJobGroupNames(cancellationToken));
}
```

I don't know why this function can't work.Maybe add Serializable attribute?But I can't.Has anyone encountered the same problem as me?

Comment: It won't work because CancellationToken isn't serializable. The error message was pretty clear if you ask me. I guess when you schedule jobs using quartz the job information has to be serializable, both the parameters to the method and the results from the method.

Comment: Most likely as you said,I used the property *quartz.serializer.type=json*,because the schedule job store type is AdoJobStore in my project,so when I got the schedule job object using quartz function,the object had to be serializable by default?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Can you give me some advice,I Had tried many ways but didn't work.I used **RemoteScheduler**,so I think get schedule data should be serializable by remote.But the  quartz.net  function *GetJobGroupNames*  change to **Task<IReadOnlyCollection<string>> GetJobGroupNames(
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)**,it caused not marked as serializable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug/flaw in 3.0.0. Async/await was brought too eagerly to remoting interfaces too where it cannot work due to legacy requirements of remoting infrastructure.

3.0.1 will fix this be removing Tasks and CancellationTokens from remote calls. The issue is tracked [here](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/571).

Comment: @loveaviva the 3.0.1 has been released so please upgrade and hopefully your problem should go away.

Comment: @Lahma When I upgraded to the 3.0.1,the method GetJobGroupNames was OK,but another method **GetJobKeys** got the same error as before,I listed the error below: 
_Quartz.Util.ReadOnlyCompatibleHashSet Not marked as serializable_ ,maybe the class **ReadOnlyCompatibleHashSet** need to be added serializable?

Comment: Sad but true, created new issue https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/576

Comment: @loveaviva 3.0.2 is now on NuGet, hopefully that will finally fix the issue thoroughly.

Comment: @Lahma Thanks.The new version 3.0.2 is OK.